# Simplify regex match groups with capturing

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I am trying to match such types of strings (5 different strings).

```
|n||0||0||0||0|
|n||n||0||0||0|
|n||n||n||0||0|
|n||n||n||n||0|
|n||n||n||n||n|
```

Where is n is variable, but other zeroes are constants, n also cannot be a zero.

I need to get such result as I hardcoded using alternative operator https://regex101.com/r/vE9hL4/1

I need to capture all numbers inside '| |' like in my regex.
Please help to simplify it.

Comment: I'm afraid I am lost. Why not explode on trim the | and explode on || to get an array per line? What are you trying to get out of this? A single array with all 5 lines, or an array per line, or just the results as a string, or?

Comment: I'm lost as well. What is the difference between |1||0| and |0||0|?

Comment: So there may be instances like `|n||0||0||n||0|` but that should NOT match because the zeros are not consecutive?

Comment: what fun homework the kids get theses days.

Comment: Thanks for answers it seems that the right way is to explode array.

Comment: By the way this is not a homework.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd do the matching; one or more positive numbers enclosed by pipe characters, optionally followed by zeroes enclosed by pipe characters.

```
$subject = '|12||13||56||1||0|';
$re = '/^((?:\|[1-9]\d*\|)+)(?:\|0\|)*$/';
```

If it matches, you can do a split based on the pipe characters themselves:

```
if (preg_match_all($re, $subject, $matches)) {
    $numbers = preg_split('/\|/', $matches[1][0], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Comment: Awesome code +1 ... Can you explain your answer? I would love to see how the regex breaks down.

Answer (score 1):

sorry didnt read part of the question, here is my revised answer...

```
^\|([0-9]*)\|(?:\|(0)\|\|(0)\|\|(0)\|\|(0)\||(?:\|([1-9]*)\|\|(0)\|\|(0)\|\|(0)\|)|(?:\|([1-9]*)\|\|([1-9]*)\|\|(0)\|\|(0)\|)|(?:\|([1-9]*)\|\|([1-9]*)\|\|([1-9]*)\|\|(0)\|)|(?:\|([1-9]*)\|\|([1-9]*)\|\|([1-9]*)\|\|([1-9]*)\|)|)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/mW5bN4/1